# Illegal instruction (Mac M1 Max 13.3)

Tags: anchor, solana-cli, anchor-test, solana-test-validator, m1

I've scoured discord and stack exchange but haven't found any solution that works for me.

When I run a local validator (Solana test validator built from source), I get error:

```
Ledger location: test-ledger
Log: test-ledger/validator.log
⠉ Initializing...
/bin/sh: line 1: 145 Illegal instruction: 4...
```

Note: the 145 number changes every time.

Any pointers on where to go from here? Without being able to run a local validator, I can't actually test my code.

---

Mac:

```
MacOS: 13.3 (22E252)
M1 Max
64GB Memory
```

Anchor Versions

```
anchor-lang = "0.27.0"
anchor-spl = "0.27.0"
```

Solana Version (v1.15.2)
[image: local solana version]

Rust Version

```
rustc 1.65.0 (897e37553 2022-11-02)
binary: rustc
commit-hash: 897e37553bba8b42751c67658967889d11ecd120
commit-date: 2022-11-02
host: x86_64-apple-darwin
release: 1.65.0
LLVM version: 15.0.0
```

Comment: using solana 1.13.7, the solana test validator works

Answer (score 1):

Hm, it definitely looks like something went wrong while building.

In general, you should always use the same version of Rust as the repo. For 1.15, you should be using Rust 1.66.1 https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/v1.15-abandoned/rust-toolchain.toml

Can you try building against master with Rust 1.67.1? Here's its toolchain file for reference https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/master/rust-toolchain.toml